# How to send Video on telegram bot using c#?

Tags: c#, video, telegram-bot

I want to send video on telegram bot using c#.i have find one api for the send video on telegram bot using "**SendVideoAsync**" using this api send i have try video upload but i am facing many issue with this and i have many confusion here and i have no idea here on any limit for the send video on telegram bot and in this api set also duration so how can set duration for that video. i have upload 1.5 and 5 mb size video is uplaod sucessfully but i have upload size 16 mb video this video is not upload on telegram bot.

this is my code =>

```
public void SendCasesOnTelegramBot()
{            
try
{
    DataSet ds = DataAccess.ExecuteDataset(Setting.ConnectionString(), "GetPostForTelegramBot");
    if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        if (ds.Tables[0] != null && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            var Image = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Url"].ToString();
            byte[] imageData = null;
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            imageData = webClient.DownloadData(Image);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageData);
            var duration = ms.Capacity;
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("abc"); 
            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append(".");
            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append(".");
            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);  

            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Type"].ToString() == "Image")  
                Bot.SendPhotoAsync("@abc", new FileToSend(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Url"].ToString(), ms), sb.ToString()); 
            else
                Bot.SendVideoAsync("@abc", new FileToSend(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Url"].ToString(), ms), duration,sb.ToString()); 
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{                
}
}
```

this is my code and i want to upload video on telegram bot but how can do that i have no idea and where is my problem in the code please tell me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [send multiple videos at the same time on telegram bot using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46148978/send-multiple-videos-at-the-same-time-on-telegram-bot-using-c)

Comment: @Stefan we have one question so can i ask??

Comment: Sure, go ahead.

Comment: i am right now working with telegram bot with c#. and i am using c# send one post image with caption and in the caption i have attache one group link. and this is group create my self in india. so now i am send post in the group and in my group one user is iranian. and iranian user this post share in to her friend in iranian. so iranian user click on this link in the caption getting error. but this link working  for indian user. so do you aware with this issue?

Comment: Nope, I am afraid I am not. Perhaps it's best to ask another question about this subject.

Comment: Nope, I am afraid I am not. Perhaps it's best to ask another question about this subject.