# send multiple videos at the same time on telegram bot using c#?

Tags: c#, video, telegram-bot

I have create one api for sending multiple videos at the same time in a loop with telegram bot using c#.

I am also getting success for uploading videos on telegram bot.

However, I am facing one issue on this task. Right now I am uploading 1 or 2 videos at the same time in the loop and it's works. But when I try with 10 or more videos, only 2 or 3 videos get uploaded successfully, and suddenly my utility stops.

It would be very helpful if someone could identify my mistake in the following code. I am not getting any errors any but my all the videos don't get uploaded and utility stops.

Here this is my code:

```
public async Task SendCasesOnTelegramBot()
{             
    DataSet ds = DataAccess.ExecuteDataset(Setting.ConnectionString(), "GetPostForTelegramBot");
    if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string VideoUrl = null;
            VideoUrl = CaseMediaPath + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Url"].ToString();        
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("abc");             

            await Bot.SendVideoAsync("@abc", video: VideoUrl, caption: sb.ToString(), replyMarkup: ReplyMarkup); 

            await Task.Delay(180000); // i am also try like this but not getting success
        }
    }
}
```

This is my API, it works very well but only for a few videos.

Comment: @Keyur PATEL do you know about this thing how can fix it?

Comment: I am not familiar with this topic at all, but based on some reading, and your code, I can give some suggestions: 1 - check the length of `ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count` to make sure it knows you have '10 or more' to send. 2 - I read the documentation on `SendVideoAsync` and it says "Telegram clients support mp4 videos (other formats may be sent as Document)" and "Bots can send video files of up to 50 MB in size.". Verify those. 3 - You can use [Try-Catch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch) to continue sending when one iteration fails in the loop.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL i am also aware with this all points and i am also check first this points and learn then after i am start this task. but idk why this type accure with me.

Comment: my code i have done with await so it's good? it's ok in the for loop await is use?or any other some changes is require for the await in the use for loop .

Comment: please any one know where is my problem then please tell me  i am new with the telegram bot.